# React Higher order component Vs Parent component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have been writing React code for long time, but when it come to choose  Higher order Component(HOC) vs Parent component, i am not able to decide which one to choose, both seems to do same thing.

1. Render Highjacking
2. Code reuse, logic and bootstrap abstraction
3. Props manipulation
4. State abstraction and manipulation

Comment: what would you consider the difference between HOC and Parent Component? to me it's the same thing...

Comment: why would chose one over other if it is same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This article has a great section comparing the 2 in the section `Appendix B: Difference with Parent Components` I'm still digging in to find out the core differences and when to use each as I have just been looking into this recently.

https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e